# How to get x:Class property of Page in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: testing, windows-phone-8.1, app.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="App6.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

I have an app. I want to get x:class of a page to distinguish pages. How to get App6.MainPage ?

I'm trying this 
I have ListControl funtion: 
    private void ListControl()
        {
            Frame currentFrame = null;
            try
            {
                currentFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

```
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        waitingControls.Add(currentFrame);
        int countChild = 1;

        while (waitingControls.Count > 0)
        {
            DependencyObject currentObject = waitingControls[0];
            waitingControls.RemoveAt(0);
            openedControls.Add(currentObject);

            countChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(currentObject);
            for (int i = 0; i < countChild; i++)
                waitingControls.Add(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(currentObject, i));
        }
    }
```

and ClearListControl Funtion

```
 private void ClearListControl()
    {
        openedControls.Clear();
        waitingControls.Clear();
    }
```

. Finally, I get properties page:

```
private async void GetPropertiesPage()
    {
         ListControl();

         for (int i = 0; i < openedControls.Count; i++)
         {
             if (openedControls[i] is Page)
             {
                 string propertiesPage = "";
                 Page page = openedControls[i] as Page;

                 //if (page.Name.Equals(""))
                 //{


                     var temp = page.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content as Frame);
                     Point screenCoords = temp.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

                     propertiesPage += ",X," + Math.Round(screenCoords.X, 0) + Environment.NewLine + ",Y," + Math.Round(screenCoords.Y, 0) + Environment.NewLine;
                     propertiesPage += ",Content," + page.Content + Environment.NewLine + ",Name," + page.Name + Environment.NewLine;
                     propertiesPage += ",AllowDrop," + page.AllowDrop.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                     StackPanel panel = (StackPanel)page.Content;

                     if (propertiesPage.Length > 0)
                     {
                         Task.Run(async () =>
                         {
                             SendData(propertiesPage);
                         }).Wait();
                     }

                     for (int j = 0; j < openedControls.Count; j++)
                     {
                         if (openedControls[j] is Grid)
                         {
                             Grid gr = (Grid)openedControls[j];
                             gr.Children.Remove(ca);
                             ca = new Canvas();
                             line = new Rectangle()
                             {
                                 StrokeThickness = 2,
                                 Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                                 Height = page.ActualHeight,
                                 Width = page.ActualWidth,
                             };
                             page.UpdateLayout();
                             ca.Children.Add(line);
                             gr.Children.Add(ca);
                             Canvas.SetTop(line, screenCoords.Y - 25);
                             Canvas.SetLeft(line, screenCoords.X);
                             await Task.Delay(2000);
                             gr.Children.Remove(ca);
                             break;

                         }
                     }

                 //}
             }
         }

         ClearListControl();
    }
```

Please help me. Thank for your help!

Comment: Can you explain what your scenario is? The `x:Class` of a page is the class used to implement the page itself.

Comment: Where is the code that is trying to get App6.MainPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You can either check the type or the typename.

Checking the type using the `is` operator is probably better because you'll get compile-time checking that it's a valid type:

```
if (page is App6.MainPage)
{
  ...
}
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you can use the typename instead:

```
if (page.GetType().FullName == "App6.MainPage")
{
  ...
}
```